# Question clarification request for "subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if it has this property: $ab \in N$ if and only if $ba \in N,$"

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

For the question:

> Prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if it has this property: $ab \in N$ if and only if $ba \in N,$ for all $a,b\in G$. $\\$

In one of the direction where I have to prove that the subgroup $N$ is normal.  Is there a different way of expressing:

If $ab\in G$, do I interpret it either as

$(1)$ the center of a group:  "$ab \in N$ if and only if $ba \in N,$", so $ab=ba$ or
$(2)$ if $c(ab) \in N$ is the same as or imply that $(ab)c \in N$.

I don't know what *if and only if* means in this context.

Thank you in advance

$Z(G)=\{a\in G\mid ag=ga \text{ for every} g\in G\}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135449/discussion-on-question-by-seth-mai-question-clarification-request-for-subgroup).

Answer (score 2):

To show this, you must prove two directions:

- If $N$ is normal, then it has the property that "$ab \in N$ if and only if $ba \in N$". This will require you to assume that $N$ is normal AND $ab \in N$, then show $ba \in N$, then assume that $N$ is normal AND $ba \in N$, then show $ab \in N$.
- If $N$ has the property that "$ab \in N$ if and only if $ba \in N$",
  then $N$ is normal. A hint for this direction is to assume $a^{-1}na \in a^{-1}Na$, for arbitrary $a \in G, n \in N$. Then consider $n = aa^{-1}n \in N$, and conclude that $N$ is normal by showing $a^{-1}Na \subseteq N$.